# Releasing an Android Wear Watch Face to Google play

Tags: android, apk, wear-os

So I've created my application based around google's example watch faces and making my own analog watch face. I created an apk using build --> generate signed apk--> Application... etc to make my apk.

Hhowever when I publish it on the app store it says I am only compatible with 6 devices, the current watch face devices, and when I look at my listing it says not compatible with any of my devices while other watch faces on the market are compatible and work just fine...

Is there something I'm doing wrong in my process of generating my apk? or could this be a code issue? (my entire app primarily follows the example code from google)

Comment: nvm i screwed up my target sdk version, i'm stupid

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

For me fix is remove usees-feature on Mobile AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

This fragment should be **only Wear `AndroidManifest.xml`**.